# Problema con el ngFor en un slider

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema al cargar unas imágenes al slider con ngFor no muestra las imágenes yo estoy usando los **pipe**  para poder mostrar las imágenes, tengo otros elementos de imágenes en la misma plantilla que se muestra y no ocurre el mismo problema, este es el código

```
<ul>
    <li data-transition="crossfade" *ngFor="let slider of sliders">
      <img class="rev-slidebg" [src]="slider.imagen | imagen:'slider'" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="30000" data-ease="Power1.easeOut"
                  data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="110" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 0" data-bgparallax="15">
      <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme large_text" data-x="left" data-hoffset="['-105','-105','0','0']" data-y="center" data-voffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap"
                  data-type="text" data-responsive-offset="on" data-frames='[{"from":"y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;","mask":"x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;","speed":1600,"to":"o:1;","delay":1200,"ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
                  data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']" data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]" data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"> {{slider.textoUno}}
                  <br> {{slider.textoDos}} 
      </div>
    </li>
   <!-- slide -->
</ul>
```

Este es el pipe

```
transform(img: string, tipo: string = 'usuario'): any {


  let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/images';  

  if(!img){
    return url + '/usuarios/cualquier';
  }

  switch(tipo){

  case 'slider':
    url += '/sliders/' + img;
  break;
  default:
    url += '/usuarios/cualquiera'

  }
  return url;
}
```

No sé cuál es el problema

Comment: Que es lo que hace tu pipe `imagen`? y que obtienes con `slider.imagen`?

Comment: Acabo de agregarlo. El pipe maneja las rutas, y el slider.imagen es el nombre del archivo o imagen que carga el component

Comment: No sera problema de tu backend?

Comment: Comprueba las `url` imprimiendo en consola.

Comment: Si comprobe las rutas y todo anda bien, tambien imprimi en la consola las demas rutas de las imagenes que no tengo este problema y si carga o lo muestra normal, pienso que pueder ser un problema de la plantilla algun conflicto con los scripts porque la plantilla es ajena, no estoy seguro es lo unico que se me ocurre.

Comment: Podrías poner una captura de pantalla de como se el carrusel en cuestión? Con la imagen sin cargar